# Popup UIPicker instead of keyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipicker

I want a UIPicker to popup instead of the keyboard when I click on a text field. Is this possible, I've been googling for awhile but can't find anything.

Does anyone have any sample code ?

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [self presentModalViewController:picker] to present a modal view controller when user click on the text field. I hoped that you know how to handle text field event

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've gone back and looked over other questions I've posted, and thanked people for there help, where it was given.

Comment: Not just thannks for people help. Their is a button under vote up/down that you can accept answer.

Comment: I get a popup box telling me that I need a reputation of 15 to vote up.

Comment: Okay, sorry I see what your saying now. This button is not very clear, I'll back over my posts now. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with the following code:

pvController = [[PickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickerView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[window addSubview:pvController.view];

It's giving me errors stating that pvController is not declared. I don't see anywhere in the tutorial that declares this value.

Comment: I've fixed this problem, please ignore the previous comment.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a more official way to do this:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
datePicker.tag = indexPath.row;
textField.inputView = datePicker;
```

Comment: Very nice, worked well.. and if you would also like to easily add done button for dismissing picker. Check out this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4827984/1154836