# UIDatePicker pop up after UIButton is pressed

Tags: iphone, animation, uidatepicker

How can I make a UIDatePicker pop up (animated) after a UIButton is pressed, and then close down again once the date is selected?  This is on the iPhone.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
canihazcode?
```

Yes, sir. Thanks for helping me procrastinating.

```
- (void)changeDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
 NSLog(@"New Date: %@", sender.date);
}

- (void)removeViews:(id)object {
 [[self.view viewWithTag:9] removeFromSuperview];
 [[self.view viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
 [[self.view viewWithTag:11] removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)dismissDatePicker:(id)sender {
 CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44);
 CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216);
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveOut" context:nil];
 [self.view viewWithTag:9].alpha = 0;
 [self.view viewWithTag:10].frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
 [self.view viewWithTag:11].frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
 [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeViews:)];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)callDP:(id)sender {
 if ([self.view viewWithTag:9]) {
  return;
 }
 CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216-44, 320, 44);
 CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216, 320, 216);

 UIView *darkView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
 darkView.alpha = 0;
 darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 darkView.tag = 9;
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)] autorelease];
 [darkView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
 [self.view addSubview:darkView];

 UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)] autorelease];
 datePicker.tag = 10;
 [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

 UIToolbar *toolBar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)] autorelease];
 toolBar.tag = 11;
 toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
 UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
 UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)] autorelease];
 [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
 [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

 [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
 toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
 datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
 darkView.alpha = 0.5;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help!  Just one question, is there a way to refrence the views that we would like to dismiss without using tags?

Comment: is the Done Button selector getting called?? didn't happen in my case??

Comment: The Done button in the toolbar won't work if you have a UITapGestureRecognizer event attached to main view. For those who have this issue can fix it by using the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14950275/705982 @raghul

Answer (score 35):

I'd propose the following (good for iOS 3.2 or better).

1. Create a text field.
2. Assign to the text field a inputView that is a UIDateTimerPicker.
3. When the button is clicked, send a "becomeFirstResponder" event - this will make the date picker slide up from the bottom for you...
4. IMHO, the best way to close the picker is not when a date is picked (since that may close it even as we are searching for the right date/time) - but attach a "Done" or "Select" button as an accessoryInput view to the keyboard.

Below is some code to show steps 2-4: (I hope I didn't forget anything in the copy/paste process...

1+3 Creating UIDateTimePicker as the text filed input view, and attaching to it a toolbar with "Done" button...

```
    // create a UIPicker view as a custom keyboard view
    UIPickerView* pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [pickerView sizeToFit];
    pickerView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

_textField.inputView = pickerView; // _textField must be an instance variable, as you'll need it...

// create a done view + done button, attach to it a doneClicked action, and place it in a toolbar as an accessory input view...
    // Prepare done button
    UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent = YES;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.tintColor = nil;
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                     action:@selector(doneClicked:)] autorelease];
    [_keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];

     // Plug the keyboardDoneButtonView into the text field...
        _textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;

// When the setDate button is clicked, call:

    - (void)setDateClicked:(id)sender {
       [_textField becomeFirstResponder]; 
    }

    - (void)doneClicked:(id)sender {
    // Write out the date...
     [_textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Good luck...

Comment: Is this really an elegant way to do this?  To take the a textfield and swap it with the date picker?  It sounds a bit strange to things this way

Comment: You don't _swap_ the text field for the date picker - you swap the KEYBOARD of the text field - and make the keyboard to be a date picker. This gives you for free everything else asked for - for free...

Comment: This is actually pretty slick!

Comment: You just invalidated an hour and a half of my frustrated development work *and* made me happy at the same time. I was trying to dismiss the keyboard and animate the presentation of the picker view. All I really needed was `-inputView` on the `UITextField`. Amazing.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Swift (1.2) version of @Reuven's code

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var pickerTextField : UITextField!
    var picker : UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // create a UIPicker view as a custom keyboard view
        self.picker = UIPickerView()

        if let picker = self.picker {
            picker.sizeToFit()
            picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.dataSource = self
            picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
            pickerTextField.inputView = picker

            // add a done button
            let toolbar = UIToolbar()
            toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
            toolbar.translucent = true
            toolbar.tintColor = nil
            toolbar.sizeToFit()

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "dismissPicker")
            toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
            pickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        }
    }

    @IBAction func showPicker() {
        pickerTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func dismissPicker() {
        pickerTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben L sir **.becomeFirstResponder()** worked !!

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)callDP:(id)sender {

    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    datePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    datePickerView.tag = 10;
    [datePickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [actionSheet addSubview:datePickerView];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];


    //[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}
```

Comment: Here's an alot easier solution.

Comment: Can you add some text within your answer to explain it to others?

Answer (score 1):

I added some comments for clarity correct me if I'm wrong (I recently started developing for iOS). Thanks Matthias Bauch! Your code example already helped me out a lot and provided lot's of insight. I hope these comments will do the same for others.

```
/*
 * Is called when the date is changed by the user.
 */
- (void)changeDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSLog(@"New Date: %@", sender.date);
}


/*
 * Releases the background, datepicker and toolbar.
 */
- (void)removeViews:(id)object {

    /*
     *  Releases the background view.
     */ 
    [[self.view viewWithTag:9] removeFromSuperview];
    /*
     *  Releases the datepicker.
     */     
    [[self.view viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
    /*
     *  Releases the toolbar.
     */     
    [[self.view viewWithTag:11] removeFromSuperview];
}


/*
 * Hides the datapicker.
 */
- (void)dismissDatePicker:(id)sender {

    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for hiding the toolbar.
     */
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44);
    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for hiding the datepicker.
     */ 
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height + 44, 320, 216);


    /*
     * Send start animation message to UIView. 
     */ 
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveOut" context:nil];
    /*
     * Set the transparency for hiding the background view.
     */ 
    [self.view viewWithTag:9].alpha = 0;
    /*
     * Set the target position for hiding the datepicker.
     */     
    [self.view viewWithTag:10].frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    /*
     * Set the target position for hiding the toolbar.
     */     
    [self.view viewWithTag:11].frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    /*
     * The method setAnimationDelegate enables knowledge on start and end of the animation.
     */         
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    /*
     * Calls the removeViews method at the end of the animation.
     */     
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeViews:)];
    /*
     * Commits the animation thread for execution. 
     */ 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


/*
 * Sets up and shows the datepicker.
 */
- (IBAction)callDP:(id)sender {

    /*
     * If view with tag exists ignore the rest of the code and exit.
     */ 
    if([self.view viewWithTag:9]) {
        return;
    }


    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for showing the toolbar.
     */
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 216 - 44, 320, 44);
    /*
     * Create a variable with the target position and size for showing the datepicker.
     */ 
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 216, 320, 216);


    /*
     * Instantiate a UIView with the frame size of the existing view.
     */
    UIView *darkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    /*
     * Set the transparency.
     */ 
    darkView.alpha = 0;
    /*
     * Set the background color.
     */ 
    darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    /*
     * Set a tag for the UIView instance to reference it by tag.
     */
    darkView.tag = 9;
    /*
     * Setup a tap gesture listener that calls the dismissDatePicker method on tap.
     */     
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
    /*
     * Add the tap gesture listener to the UIView.
     */ 
    [darkView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    /*
     * Adds the subview on top of all the other subviews.
     */
    [self.view addSubview:darkView];


    /*
     * Instantiate a UIDatePicker and set the initial frame with the datepicker outside of the view.
     */
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)];
    /*
     * Set a tag for the UIDatePicker instance to reference it by tag.
     */ 
    datePicker.tag = 10;
    /*
     * Add a listener that listens for changing values in the datepicker which then calls the change date method.
     */     
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    /*
     * Adds the subview on top of all the other subviews.
     */ 
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];


    /*
     * Instantiate a UIToolbar and set the initial frame with the toolbar outside of the view.
     */
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
    /*
     * Set a tag for the UIToolbar instance to reference it by tag.
     */     
    toolBar.tag = 11;
    /*
     * Set a style for the UIToolbar.
     */ 
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    /*
     * Instantiate a spacer UIBarButtonItem.
     */     
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    /*
     * Instantiate a done UIBarButtonItem on click this will call the dismissDatePicker method.
     */     
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
    /*
     * Set the created UIBarButtonItems to the toolbar.
     */     
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
    /*
     * Adds the subview on top of all the other subviews.
     */ 
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];


    /*
     * Start animation.
     */ 
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
    /*
     * Set the target position for showing the toolbar.
     */ 
    toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    /*
     * Set the target position for showing the datepicker.
     */     
    datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    /*
     * Set the transparency for showing background view.
     */     
    darkView.alpha = 0.5;
    /*
     * Commits the animation thread for execution. 
     */     
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```