# Issue about iRolegameAppDelegate

Tags: objective-c

I want to build a `UIPickerView` with `ActionSheet`. Some codes was found in Stack Overflow (link [Problem in Datepicker and alertsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850231/problem-in-datepicker-and-alertsheet))

Error occured when I tried to use it. It showed **iRolegameAppDelegate** was not defined.

```
-(IBAction)DatePickerView {iRolegameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iRolegameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
pickerViewDate = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"How many?"
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Is there anyone can tell me how to define it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is presumably your application delegate. You need to import the header file:

```
#import "iRolegameAppDelegate.h"
```

At the top of the .m file this method is in.

If that *isnt* your app delegate, then you are copying from an example you don't understand.