# How to disable the UIDatePicker after selecting the date?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uidatepicker

Iam using the following code for the UIDatePicker, whatever the date iam selecting it is being displayed in the  label. But i need to close the Picker after selecting the date. Is this possible please suggest me.

I am using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create label
    label = [[UILabel alloc] init]; 
    label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    //Use NSDateFormatter to write out the date in a friendly format
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                  [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [df release];
    [self.view addSubview:label]; 
    [label release];

    // Initialization code
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 250)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
    [datePicker release];
}

- (void)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender{
    //Use NSDateFormatter to write out the date in a friendly format
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                  [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [df release];
}
```

Comment: have you seen this ?.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4824319/1865424

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you to do something like this:

[image]

to use a toolbar with a Done button and maybe a Cancel Button
...

This is just a quick implementation, it may help

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 44)];
textField.text         = @"Date";
[self.view addSubview:textField];

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
toolbar.barStyle   = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

UIBarButtonItem *itemDone  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:textField action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
UIBarButtonItem *itemSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

toolbar.items = @[itemSpace,itemDone];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
datePicker.minimumDate   = [NSDate date];
datePicker.date          = [NSDate date];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangePickerDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
textField.inputView          = datePicker;

[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 3):

You Have to use button for click on Background to hide the DATEPICKER from your view.

```
-(IBAction)backGroundClick:(id)sender
{
    [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe better then removing from superview would be setting userInteraction to NO 
and you need button for "done", as in where the user is ready to finish chosing date

```
-(IBAction)buttonDoneClick:(id)sender
{
    [datePicker setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work.
Tapping on the date label will enable the DatePicker as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40);
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                  [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerView)];

    [self.view addSubview:label];


}

- (void)datePickerView
{
    // Initialization code
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 250)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}


- (void)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender{
    //Use NSDateFormatter to write out the date in a friendly format
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                  [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

}
```

and using the following method Picker will be resigned from the view on tapping outside the Picker.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
}
```