# UIBarButtonItem and UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` where i added a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
[self.myView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

I then add a `UIToolBar` with a button to the view:

```
UIToolbar *topBar = [[UIToolbar alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.myView.frame.size.width, 44)];
topBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

UIBarButtonItem *logout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logout)];

[topBar setItems:@[logout] animated:NO];
```

I'm having an issue where I click on the logout button, and my tap recognier fires instead of my logout action. If I click and hold, then the logout action will fire (I'm guessing the tap recognizer is failing so lets the buttion action fire).

how can I not fire the gesture recognizer when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same problem. Because I don't want to introduce container views (the UIToolbar should cover my existing view). With the help of Patrick.Ji's coarsely pointing I came up with this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate of the gesture to `self`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *mainTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mainTapGesture:)];
    mainTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:mainTapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: I hate using such hacks but it's contained. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the view in your tap recognizer. If it is your logout button, let the touch fail to pass it up the chain via `super`.

Alternatively, make sure your toolbar is not a subview of your view. Instead, have a container view containing with your toolbar and your content view, and add the gesture recognizer to  this content view.

Comment: the view of the recognizer is always the myView. I am checking it in the tapDetected: method. i'll use a content view if nothing else works.

Answer (score -1):

implement this delegate method of UIGestureRecognizer (remember to set your tapRecognizer.delegate = self)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:   (UITouch *)touch {

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. A `UIBarbuttonItem` is not a `UIView` subclass. Hence the view of the touch will never be of that class. The UIView subclass in which a `UIBarButtonItem` is transfered when displayed are private classes (e.g. `UIToolbarButton` or `UIToolbarTextButton`)